# How to track correctly in ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the two fragments (called A and B in this question) and I place these in ViewPager.
I need to track for logging when each fragment is appeared.

For example A and B are placed on ViewPager. A is on the left side and B is on the right side.

The requirements are below.

**On ViewPager:**

- Track A when the user first open the ViewPager because the A is appeared at first.
- Track B when the user on A swiped left ViewPager because the B is appeared.
- Track A when the user on B swiped right ViewPager because the A is appeared.

**On Changing App:**

- Track A when the user on A open other app and return to this fragment.
- Track B when the user on B open other app and return to this fragment.

**On Fragment  Transaction:**

- Track A when the user on A go to other fragment or activity and return to this fragment.
- Track B when the user on B go to other fragment or activity and return to this fragment.

**On Mix Situation:**

- Track A when the user on A go to other fragment or activity and then change the app  and then return to this app and back to A fragment.
- Track B when the user on B go to other framgnet or activity and then change the app and then return to this app and back to B fragment.

In Don't Keep Activity mode and Keep Activity mode, I would like to track as I specified.

Answer (score 0):

you should override `setUserVisibleHint` method in your fragments and it will tell you when user focus on that specific fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
   if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But `setUserVisibleHint` is not called with the situation which  `isVisibleToUser` and `isResumed` are true, when the fragment is appeared at first. And The method is not called when go to other fragment and then return to the original fragment, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener to get current page of pager.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but the listener methods are not called when the fragment is appeared first.